# How to set Hint to a Button in android

Tags: android-layout, android-button

I have an app, which collects person's info, in that i have button for showing datepicker for collecting Person's DOB, now I need to display hint on that button. I set the hint s to all UI components, i can see the hints in edit text but not in button. How to refactor this problem, Any Help is appreciated... Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got corrected, I used the following attribute in the `<button>` tag as follows :

```
 <Button
        .
        .
    android:hint="01/02/1999"
    android:ellipsize="start" />
```

The Hint appears on the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom button by layering a text view over a button, check schematic below:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <Button></Button>
    <TextView></TextView>
</FrameLayout>
```